# VLAN causes error: Failed to start Raise network interfaces

Tags: networking, interface

I am trying to set up a DHCP server and need to configure VLANs on the interface of the server. I have followed these two guides, [guide1](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/vlan) [guide2](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-configure-linux-virtual-local-area-network-vlan.html) , mainly but everything I have tried results in the failed Raise error. Following in my network interfaces config.

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto ens160
iface ens160 inet static
        address 10.10.1.5
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.10.1.0
        broadcast 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.10.1.1
        dns-nameservers 10.10.1.1 8.8.8.8

#VLAN 101
auto ens160.101
iface ens160.101 inet static
        address 10.10.10.5
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.10.10.0
        broadcast 255.255.255.0
        gateway 10.10.10.1
        dns-nameservers 10.10.10.1 8.8.8.8
        vlan-raw-devices ens160
```

If you need more information please ask and I'll try and reply as soon as possible.

Thanks

Comment: "failed Raise error" is? Your interfaces is down? You do not have traffic? Also please give us output from `ifconfig` and `route -n`

Comment: @2707974 Yes the interfaces are down, Failed raise error refers to the error in the title. if I remove the VLAN from the config file it works fine and the interface becomes active. the following links are snapshots to my ifconfig, http://puu.sh/w1uuN/3ef448bab5.png, and route -n, http://puu.sh/w1uAQ/6f88dae0f7.png . Here is a link to a snap of the error as well http://puu.sh/w1uEO/1b600ade35.png .

Comment: Based on your snapshots only I can tell is that your network working. `ifconfig` say that you have `rx/tx` aka out and in packets. In routing table you have both network and default gw is `10.10.10.1`.  Can you ping some host in `10.10.1.0/24` network and in network `10.10.10.0/24`?